# Cannot get Guitar Rig 5 sounds recorded into Ableton Live 9

Tags: guitar, recording, homerecording, live, ableton

I cannot get Guitar Rig 5 sounds and patches recorded into Ableton Live 9.
Ableton Live 9 only records clean sounds from my guitar.

Comment: can you add some information on how you have your recording setup configured. What are the connections between guitar-guitar rig-ableton etc

Comment: Thanks Dr Mayhem I am using a Focusrite Scarlet 2i2 usb to connect my guitar into my computer via usb. And I connect my amp in focusrite output to get the sound. So when I run Guitar Rig 5, I can get the sounds out from it in my amp. However I don't get those effects recorded into Ableton.

Comment: So it sounds like Guitar Rig is only passing your sound with effects to the Focusrite output, and Ableton is using the clean bus in that Guitar Rig is using. You need to ensure it is passing it to the bus that Ableton is using.

Comment: Can you please explain how to ensure Guitar Rig is passing its output to the bus that Ableton is using.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is Guitar Rig 5 running as a plugin within Ableton? I think it should be. Also, ensure the track it's on is armed for recording. Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

here's the simple setup:

Guitar >amp >scarlet 2i2 >Ableton....

then in the ableton, set the input/output to:

1. track 1: guitar input, add guitar rig vst , set the output to sends only. Set the monitoring from [auto] to [in].
2. track 2: set the input to track 1, then make sure to set the monitoring from [auto] to [in].
3. then arm the record in track 2.
   record track 2.

that should be fine.

hope this helps...